# two breakers energize the same luminaire, what should I do?

Tags: electrical

I'm working on a friend's house to replace a ceiling light fixture controlled by a wall switch.   In the process of trying to figure out which breaker de-energizes the fixture, I've determined that TWO of them do: in a logical-or manner, that is, if either or both breakers are "on", then the fixture is energized (I must turn off BOTH breakers to de-energize the fixture).   The two breakers are both single-pole and are not neighbors; they are 6 spaces apart on the same side of the panel (same column of breakers).

I tore into the fixture and there are three 12-2 NM cables coming into its junction box.  Disconnecting them all and testing: #1 is energized by one breaker, #2 is energized by the other breaker, and #3 is a switch leg/loop (zero ohms when the switch is "on" infinite when it's "off").   The hots from #1 and #2 were both tied to #3, and the other conductor in #3 to the light's hot input. I can only conjecture that the original electrician thought #2 was just a continuation of the circuit of #1.  Oddly too, there seem to be no other loads (with both breakers off, I can't find anything else in the entire house that is de-energized).

Is there any valid reason for this to be wired this way ?  What should I do to rectify this inappropriate wiring ?  Simply remove #1 or #2 from the fixture and tie it off in its own box ?

FWIW, I've found a couple of other profoundly stupid things in this house: an extension cord that was repaired with the 3 conductors scrambled (not just hot and neutral reversed, which is bad enough), and a luminaire where the wires are just poked into the attic and taped to the romex (not inside a box, and using masking tape).  But ... this is the first screwup that looks like it was done by the original electrician.

Comment: I wonder if the "second circuit" cable was actually a continuation of the first circuit, and it goes onward to another switch box where the second circuit is present, and they're bridged *there* because the electrician just tied all neutrals and all always-hots.  That is to say, the improper joining of the two circuits might not have happened *here*: it could have happened anywhere along this "ring circuit" to borrow the British term.

Comment: Good point.  But if in fact it IS a ring, it doesn't matter where I break it (as far as safety or of practicality) - and for that matter, the question of where the "improper joining" took place is really a matter of semantics (for lack of a better term).   Unless of course putting the discontinuity in the wrong place overloads one of the circuits.  But since I can't identify a single other load on this circuit (or circuits) other than the light in question, that is doubtful.

Comment: Anyhow, the house hasn't burned down in the 35 years it's stood.  But I just don't want to make things WORSE by re-wiring this light.   Oh, and did I mention it's a Federal Pacific panel (no joke) ...

Comment: I re-titled and re-worded my OP to focus on the remedy.

Comment: OK I edited my answer.  TLDR: map the loop and figure out the best place to break it - likely someplace where 2 circuits would be really useful... that being why the original guy ran 2 circuits there.

Comment: Ok thanks.   Not sure what mapping there is to do though, since there appear to be no other loads on either circuit.

Comment: Interesting. 2 dedicated circuits for 1 lamp?  Maybe the last guy had a *really big light* lol!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: What you have is an "accidental ring circuit". Somewhere, in some box (clearly not this one), both circuits arrived into the same junction box. That's fine as long as a Great Wall is kept between the two circuits' hots *and neutrals*. (grounds should be combined).  However, at one box or another, someone merged the circuits by accident.

My general view is "Previous work was done that way for a really good reason, even if it got broke later".  So in an "accidental loop" situation, I would map the entire circuit(s) to find all the boxes that are served by this "loop".   In one of those boxes, it will be obvious *and probably, even advantageous* to have that box served by 2 circuits instead of one (i.e. the reason they did that).  I would break the loop there. For the most advantage.

---

---

---

That's very likely what has happened. Somebody brought a "switch loop" into a box containing an unrelated circuit or branch of a circuit.

Code requires you keep a "Great Wall" between the unrelated "circuits", they don't go as far as requiring a physical divider, but maybe they should.

And then fools get in there and start muxing around, and stuff like this shows up.  It's the old "try things until you find something that works" fallacy that I often warn people about; lots of arrangements will *work* but then will set the stage for problems later.

Not the least of the problems here is that you have 40A worth of hot power that could potentially be trying to return on a single 20A neutral wire.  (or 30/15 if applicable).  There are also issues with magnetic fields from current not being balanced/equal in cables, all sorts of "wrong".

I agree - a careful examination of the wiring is called for.  I recommend a viewpoint of "the people doing this weren't *complete* idiots, they surely were trying to go for something here".

One fast way of *validating* a given circuit is to temporarily put its hot and neutral wires on a GFCI breaker. If there's any improper crossing of circuits going on, the GFCI will trip the instant a load is applied. One must be careful of MWBCs, but an MWBC can be validated (as isolated from other circuits) by putting both its hots on the GFCI hot lug.

Comment: That's a cool idea about temporarily using a GFCI

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd outlaw MWBC.   Just to save 25% on copper costs ?

Comment: @RustyShackleford presumably you mean outlaw in detached residential?

Comment: This would be better if it didn't begin with "Yes" (and repeats "Yes" in another paragraph) when the titular question is one you're really answering with "No". While you do explain you're agreeing with the question author's analysis of what probably happened to get to this point, the current wording could be confusing to someone not reading closely. It doesn't help that you never *directly* answer the titular question. I think, perhaps, the issue is you wrote it from, and a lot of us read it from, the point of view of "this is obviously and clearly wrong", so you just jump into an explanation.

Comment: "an MWBC can be validated (as isolated from other circuits) by putting both its hots on the GFCI hot lug." Doesn't this create the very problem with 40A on a 20A neutral that you describe above, though? Wouldn't you need a double-pole GFCI to do this safely?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica A worthy question.  But when you merge a MWBC so both hot legs are fed from the same breaker lug, effectively it stops being a MWBC, and current is limited by that breaker. So the sum of the two #12 hots will be say 20A, and the neutral is limited to 20A.

Comment: @jay613 Yeah, they're awesome in industrial lighting.  Not just that you can put 3 effective circuits in 4 wires instead of 6 (EMT is ground), but also the impact they have on thermal derate in conduits.  3-phase MWBC lets you put 9 effective circuits in 1 conduit instead of only 4 single-phase.  With 277V circuits, that's 40KW, you're lighting up a whole CostCo on twelve #12 wire lol...

Comment: I had a chance to buy a deliberately designed device that is supposed to be on two circuits at once. I'm willing to bet it plays fast and loose with the neutral; and there's no way it's not tying the grounds of the two circuits together but it exists for a very good reason.

Comment: @Joshua there's a surprising number of those. I just saw a wood stove that took a 15A circuit for its trivial 120V loads, but had a massive electric emergency strip heat (100A nameplate, 150A breaker). Then there are those "2 circuit combiners to make 240V" rigs, I hear some are made with actual interlocks to do it almost safely!

Comment: A wood stove with electric heat strips ?  Wow.   Yeah, I wonder why equipment manufacturers can't bother to put a simple and cheap piece of circuitry in, to avoid stuff like this (2 circuits).   My range runs the oven off 240vac, but because the internal logic (gas controls etc) run off 120vac, it requires a neutral wire; pretty annoying.

Comment: @RustyShackleford many of those manufacturers sell the appliance in the Philippines, which is wired like us, but without neutral.  They install a simple transformer to serve the internal 120V loads.  But oven light is 220V so they can use indigenous bulbs.

Comment: But yeah, as far as MWBC, I should first make sure the two breakers are driving separate NM cables (as opposed to two conductors from a 3-wire cable).

Comment: In case you guys aren't auto-notified, I tore into the thing and edited OP.

Comment: What's an example of why it'd be advantageous to have two circuits in the same box ?   A switch box (perhaps 4-gang) from which lots of loads are driven ?

Comment: Right off the top of my head, a bathroom light-fan-heater where the heater is a retrofit.  Not enough headroom on the light-fan circuit so they bring in another circuit for heater.  Or really almost any 3-way could result in this, since the "far" 3-way might be in a multi-gang box with other switches on other circuits.

Comment: Ok, well I can't find ANYTHING else on the "ring", so I guess i'll just disconnect at this light.

Comment: Found a MWBC to the kitchen, tied to two independent single-pole breakers.   At least they're neighbors, so hopefully opposite phase ...

Comment: Found another amusing thing: They tapped off a 3-way switch circuit to add an outlet - so the outlet is driven by a traveler and neutral.   So if the switch in the other room is in the wrong position, then the outlet is dead.  And ... wait for it ... the outlet is for the propane tankless water heater.   Guess I'll remove the switch in the other room, and send hot&neutral to the water heater room (and discard the third conductor); so the water heater will always be energized, and the light in that room can only be switched there.

Comment: Looked in the panel, and the single-pole breakers alternate black & red wires. So I reckon the whole house was done with MWBCs. I can't tell for sure how they're paired up, because the NM sheaths don't extend into the box - everything comes in from the crawlspace via a 2" PVC nipple, so I guess they just put the conductors thru it (haven't looked in the crawl yet). Which makes me wonder why some of the boxes I've looked in just have power coming in via a white&black cable (incl. the light that lives on 2 circuits).  I guess it's ok to come off an MWBC with a 2-wire w/ one of the hots though.

Comment: On your GFCI test, I guess the GFCI needs to be at the breaker (so the breaker connected to the "line" terminals, and the branch circuit conductors connected to the "load" terminals).  Not just hung off the circuit somewhere; if you do that, and the load is just a light bulb or something, of course the neutral and hot currents will be balanced and the thing won't trip.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133452/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-reinstate-monica-two-breakers-energize-the-same).

Answer (score 5):

The live "tied together" from two breakers is definitely not allowed, but two different circuits in one outlet box is allowed. Disconnect the tie.

Comment: I'm not sure "tied together" is the situation, but I can't think of another explanation.  But I'm going to tear into the thing soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar thing in my house. Two separate breakers control one light. The light in question is on a 3 way switch. I believe they share a neutral. I discovered the issue when trying to install a GFCI outlet (which wasn't possible, because it would always trip). I think the issue was cheap/lazy wiring standards when the house was built/remodeled. Its a problem, but not a problem that needs immediate fixing. (unless you already have stuff torn apart)

Comment: Better to use the GFCI problem as an excuse to hunt down the root problem.  Likely the original wiring can be salvaged by use of smart switches.  Or, you can still install the GFCI receptacle,  you just have to contain the urge to use the "LOAD" terminals for the extra wires.  Read the instructions (required anyway by NEC 110.2) and it will say how to hook 2 wires to Line screws.